# How to Query the COM Apartment State for the Current Thread

Tags: c++, com, native, apartment-state

The .NET Thread class has a handy function GetApartmentState() that returns the apartment of context of the thread. Is there a similar **Co<something-something>** function for native code (C++, C)? I feel like I should know, since I've been programming COM for almost 10 years, but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`CoGetApartmentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I guess my eyesight is not very good, as I just been scanning the list you linked to.

Comment: Note that this is a new API available in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. Please read the article thoroughly for full details.

Comment: @EuroMicelli The article also explains what to do on older systems.